# Outlook 2003 won't send mail

Tags: email, exchange, outlook, outlook-2003

A colleague's e-mail has just started playing up - he's using Outlook/Office 2003 on a Win XP SP3 machine.  Yesterday his mail has suddenly stopped being received, although there are no errors of any kind that i can see.  It was only noticed because he didn't have any replys all day.

His e-mails seem to send fine - no errors come up, the mail goes into Sent Items as usual, but it never arrives at it's destination.  However, when mail is sent from Outlook Web Access, e-mails send fine.  All connections to the server appear fine and outlook is 'connected' but  I've had a look at the message tracking on our Exchange 2003 server and no messages are appearing when sent from outlook, only when sent through OWA.

Where should i be looking ?

Thanks.

Comment: He hasn't gone into offline mode has he? Does the mail he thinks has been sent appear in is OWA sent items?

Comment: "I've had a look at the message tracking on our Exchange 2003 server" makes me think this question would be more suited for ServerFault.com. Voting to migrate it there.

Comment: Sim: Thanks for the reply.  No, it's not in offline mode - The icon in bottom-right corner is orange, it's online and connected to Exchange.  Yes the mail sent from outlook appears in OWA in sent items, yet it doesn't appear in message tracking on the Exchange server and it never arrives.

Comment: I think if you're offline, then the messages stay in your outbox folder, not in your sent items.

Comment: The opportunity came to replace the machine (it was low-spec hardware) so i retired it without rectifying the issue.  Lazy i know, but time was of the essence.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Create a new Outlook profile with the same account settings. I´ve got a similar problem a few weeks ago. After i created a new profile it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a corrupted OST file.  Change the user to NOT use cached Exchange mode.  Send a message and see if it is delivered.   If you must have cached mode,  rename/move/delete the OST file, and then set the cache flag back on.  This will create a new cache(OST) file, and download the items from the server, hopefully solving the corruption issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is roaming, check if telnet to port 25,110,143 is occurring. Since you are not facing an issue with sending mails from the web interface a host of factors including connectivity, your hosts software firewall/antivirus settings or as a few other suggested
before me, a corruption of your Mail Client profile could cause this to happen.

If you have been provided by a web interface to sent out mails, try using that for a while till you diagnose the root cause of your current problem.